# OpenMP cannot free threads when

Tags: multithreading, openmp

this is my testing code. I test this code in windows 7 with vs2008. First  I create a thread(A), and then in thread(A) i call openmp to do some optimization. When thread(A) is closed, the threads created by openmp are not free. The number of threads in this process keep growing. Can anyone tell why and how to fix it. Thanks^^!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i)
    {
        cout << "Child thread: i = " << i << endl;
    }

    return 0L;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);

        DWORD   dwExitCode;
        WaitForSingleObject( thread, INFINITE );
        GetExitCodeThread(thread, &dwExitCode);
        if (dwExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE)
        {
            printf("current thread still running!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i)
    {
        cout << "main thread: i = " << i << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My first question would be why are you doing that, multithreading your code and then calling OpenMP from each one of the initial threads. There shouldn't be a need for it. If you want to parallelize your program, you use OpenMP directly. My first theory would be that the implementation of the main threads is clashing, somehow, with the OpenMP runtime.

Comment: In fact, I use OpenMP in my DLL. Some other multithreaded program call my DLL, then i found this problem.